# VPN Gobbles default connection

Tags: vpn, routing

I'm not feeling the best, so I'm remoting in to work with a VPN. However, it gobbles out all outgoing connections, which means putty sessions and internet usage don't work when the VPN is connected (because it goes through the VPN instead of my local internet.)

Is there a way I can force my connections to go through my local router instead of through the VPN connection? On a winxp box at the moment.

On the bright side, that means I can't let SO distract me while I'm working, so maybe I should let it stay this way!!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to setup your PC to not use the VPN gateway as the default gateway. Here's Microsoft's help on the matter

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317025

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't list your VPN client this may or may not be an option, but you can enable local network access. I had this same issue you had with a Cisco IPSec VPN connection.

Comment: It's a Palo Alto Networks VPN.